# A "B" inside a triangle symbol in connector drawing datasheet

Tags: connector, datasheet, drawing

I was checking a drawing datasheet, and I noticed this symbol. A *B* inside a triangle. As seen on the screenshot, the symbol is on the side of the table that indicates the pinout.

I can't find out anywhere what it means. Any help?

[image]

Found this info at the bottom of the drawing datasheet

[image]

Comment: Link the data sheet please. It probably means section B.

Comment: @Andyaka not availble online

Comment: Please show a full image of that page of the data sheet and, also give the part number and manufacturer.

Comment: "Informational" or "note" B.

Comment: @rdtsc could be "note" B, yes

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Without any triangle it'll be a general note.

With triangle it'll be an indication for revision. In your question, the B-in-triangle is placed quite close to the row-2 of the table. It indicates that there is a revision in the row-2, and the explanation shows that the content is changed from "PLUG NO - 3" to "MOLEX NO - 3".